# Bases of Ker (or Null) space after linear transormation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $N_P$ be a matrix whose columns form the basis of a Ker($P$). Let $N_{\hat{P}}$ be a matrix whose columns form the basis of a Ker$\left(P\begin{bmatrix}A & 0 & 0\\
0& I& 0\\
0& 0& I\end{bmatrix}\right)$ for matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A & 0 & 0\\
0& I& 0\\
0& 0& I\end{bmatrix}$ of appropriate dimensions, where $A$ is an invertible matrix and $I$ is an identity matrix. The relation between $N_P$ and $N_{\hat{P}}$ is given (in a paper) as
$$
N_{\hat{P}}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} & 0 & 0\\
0& I& 0\\
0& 0& I\end{bmatrix}N_P.
$$
I am quite confused why this is true. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Denote $B=\begin{bmatrix}A&0&0\\0&I&0\\0&0&I\end{bmatrix}$. The hypothesis on $N_P$ can be translated as $PN_P=0$. Similarly, all you have to explain is why $\;(PB)N_{\hat P}=0$. The key to this is to determine the inverse of $B$ in function of the inverse of $A$ (think of block multiplication).

Comment: OK Thanks. If I understand correctly: for $PBN_{\hat{P}}$ to be 0, it must satisfy $BN_{\hat{P}}=N_P$, thus obtaining the desired equality. Is it correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct. Let me add it is ($N_{\hat P}$) *one* solution for a basis of $\ker PB$ (as $N_P$ is *one* solution for $ker P$).